# Put in AWS Dynamo using python Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in Dynamo

[image: DB]

Now I am trying to add a new row(product) in the table.
when I am trying this with API gateway, I created a resource and created a post method with request mode **Product**

**Request Model**

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title" : "Error Schema",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "ID" : { "type" : "string" },
    "Catogory" : { "type" : "string" },
    "SubCatogory" : { "type" : "string" },
    "ProductName" : { "type" : "string" }
    
  }
}
```

When I am trying to invoke lambda using API gateway,

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

when I dig deep I am getting error as

```
Invalid type for parameter Item, value:     {
      "SubCatogory": "Car",
      "ID": "6",
      "ProductName": "jeep wrangler",
      "Catogory": "Vehicle"
    }, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>.
```

My request body looks like this.

```
    {
      "SubCatogory": "Car",
      "ID": "6",
      "ProductName": "jeep wrangler",
      "Catogory": "Vehicle"
    }
```

how to retrieve data and add in DB

**Edit 1**

Adding the Code used in Lambda

```
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = dynamodb.Table('Products')
    request_params = event['body']
    project_json = request_params
    response = table.put_item(Item=project_json)
    # response = event['body']
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response
    }
```

when I am trying to returning  `event['body']` I can see the response as as same as inputs

**EDIT 2**

Have tried to convert json string to dict with json.loads(request_params)

```
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = dynamodb.Table('Products')
    request_params = event['body']
    product_json = json.loads(request_params)
    response = table.put_item(Item=product_json)
    # response = json.loads(event['body'])
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response
    }
```

Getting error as

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
```

Comment: show the code that does the insertion

Comment: @gold_cy have updated it in question

Comment: Suspect that your body is a JSON string and you need to JSON.parse() it to an object.

Comment: @jarmod, I am new to python, I have tried json.loads()
but still dint work
`Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response`
this is the error when I tried with   project_json = json.loads(request_params)

Comment: In the same way as the event body was a JSON string that you have to parse with `json.loads(event['body'])`, the response body should also be a JSON string. So use `json.dumps(response)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

1. you need to parse the event body if it's JSON using `Item=json.loads(event['body'])`
2. you need to stringify the returned dict using `'body': json.dumps(response)`